# Change approval status after insert item via Sharepoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, versioning

I recently noticed that by modifying the column of an item in a list with active versioning, however much the item is approved, it changes the status to draft.
When faced with this problem I decided to create a list only to make these modifications without the active versioning, but this time I tested with a user that he only has read permission, he was not able to insert for example his ID in the column. It says "You do not have permission...".
Does anyone have an idea how to solve any of the above situations?

Thank you.

Comment: Read Only permissions still apply when using the REST API. The service request makes the call using the current user's credentials so, no writes/edits can be made by a user with Read Only permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `SystemUpdate()` in code, not `Update()`. It will be changed as administrator and no new version will be created.

But with REST request you are not able to do SystemUpdate, you can do it with CSOM only.